# Error Sframe iPython

Tags: python, sframe

I'm attending a ML course on Coursera, and I'm having trouble opening a file with `SFrame`, when I try, this error appears:

```
sf = graphlab.Sframe.read_csv('people.csv')

******AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-42b242f73eda> in <module>()
----> 1 sf = graphlab.Sframe.read_csv('people.csv')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Sframe'******
```

I tried to run also Kernel > Restart

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-07d139e1ed65> in <module>()
----> 1 Kernel > Restart

NameError: name 'Kernel' is not defined
```

I'm new to Python, could anyone help me please?

Comment: print `graphlab.__file__` to make sure that you are actually importing the `graphlab` package, and not some file/folder in your current working directory named ***graphlab***.

Answer (score 1):

The f should be capitalised in sframe.

```
sf = graphlab.SFrame.read_csv('people.csv')
```